# how to monitor windows vpn connectivity?

Tags: windows, vpn, network-monitoring

I have set up Windows 10 built-in VPN for the use of one program and I have sense that this connectivity is bad. Generally my Windows machine has very reliable network connection but connectivity in particular VPN is bad. How can I monitor the connectivity for that one particular VPN? I just need the up-time and down-time intervals for this VPN and also the reason why particular down-time happens.

I am not aware about Windows tools for doing this. I know Wireshark but it generates too much low-level information - e.g. there are data about keep-alive packets and responses on them but I would like to get more general information - just about down-times and reasons behind them.

Answer (score 6):

Performance Monitor (perfmon.exe) is great for monitoring in windows.

Run perfmon.exe and click the plus button to add the counters that you want to monitor.
Depending on your VPN, you probably want the IPsec counters. Add everything that says IPsec in the name, then watch the live graph to determine the interesting counters for your setup. From there you can use the Data Collector Sets to set up logging of your counters.

As for determining the why of connectivity issues, you can use Event Viewer eventvwr.exe for that. Just look for the time of the drop from perfmon, and there will be a few events in the Application and/or System logs at that time.